# Installing MethylNet into PyCharm

Tags: package, pycharm

I'm trying to install the MethylNet package into PyCharm. After installing R and putting it on the PATH env variable (solving a previous error), I'm getting the output that follows. Sorry if this it's something obvious, but I'm not particularly knowledgeable about installing packages on the command line (I have tried that and gotten the same output). I have installed the conda and anaconda packages, as well as various others. If anyone knows a better (or any) way of installing MethylNet into PyCharm I'd be really grateful =^).

Tried: Installing via PyCharm package manager.
Result: The following output
Tried: Installing Pycharm's recommended commands in command console
Result: The following output again...

```
Collecting methylnet
  Using cached methylnet-0.1.3.tar.gz (58 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting pymethylprocess>=0.1.5
  Using cached pymethylprocess-0.1.6.tar.gz (40 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml in c:\users\gauli\pycharmprojects\pythonproject2\venv\lib\site-packages (from methylnet) (0.17.21)
Collecting statsmodels
  Using cached statsmodels-0.13.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (9.2 MB)
Collecting mlxtend
  Using cached mlxtend-0.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting dask
  Using cached dask-2023.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting rpy2==2.9.4
  Using cached rpy2-2.9.4.tar.gz (194 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [28 lines of output]
  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
  Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
  Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
  
  R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
  You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
  GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
  For more information about these matters see
  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
  
  'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\gauli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9uuekabg\rpy2_51c8d9569185446f9b15d7961d00ed24\setup.py", line 374, in <module>
      ri_ext = getRinterface_ext()
    File "C:\Users\gauli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9uuekabg\rpy2_51c8d9569185446f9b15d7961d00ed24\setup.py", line 269, in getRinterface_ext
      ldf = shlex.split(' '.join(rexec.cmd_config('--ldflags')))
    File "C:\Users\gauli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9uuekabg\rpy2_51c8d9569185446f9b15d7961d00ed24\setup.py", line 221, in cmd_config
      output = subprocess.check_output(cmd,
    File "C:\Users\gauli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "C:\Users\gauli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('C:\\PROGRA~1\\R\\R-42~1.2\\bin\\x64\\R', 'CMD', 'config', '--ldflags')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
  C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-42~1.2\bin\x64\R CMD config --ldflags
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```